# Why does my MacBook Air (almost) always lock when I shut the lid?

Tags: password, login, system-settings

In system preferences, under Security and Privacy, the "Require Password" box is *not* checked. Interestingly, even when I have entered my password and the lock icon is open, I cannot check this box - I click on it, and the checkmark briefly appears and then goes away.

Despite the box not being checked, my computer almost always makes me type in a password when I open it or after it goes into the screen saver.

Occasionally, it does unlock automatically, but when it does so, I cannot click or interact with any windows, and I have to shut and open my screen again and type the password in order to actually use my computer.

I am using a MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Lets be clear do you mean it always *LOCKS* or does it indeed log you out? EG quit out of all open applications and any background apps you have run automatically, and then prompt to log in? Your question *seems* to conflate the two.

Comment: Does your MBA go to *sleep* during the period of inactivity (when the lid is closed)?

Comment: @SteveChambers It locks. I have clarified the question.

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure how to tell if it's sleeping or not, but I think so? Essentially, it is behaving as if I have "Require Password [immediately] after sleep or screen saver begins" checked, even though it is not checked.

Comment: See this Apple [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202824).  When you close your lid, you put it to *sleep*.  The password setting is for the screen saver.

Comment: @Allan My screen saver settings don't have any options for a password.   Also, changing or turning off my energy saver settings does not affect whether or not my computer requires a password after closing the lid or screen saver.

Answer (score 1):

If you close your laptop then immediately reopen it does it lock itself? also in the settings it specifies that it will not lock after "sleep or screen saver begins." Which means what may be happening is that your MacBook is passed a sleep state and has entered [standby mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202124) and locked itself.

Side Note: Why would you want your mac not to lock itself. Closing the lid does not protect against potential attackers if you have this setting disabled. It also makes it harder to lock you computer when you want to.

Comment: Yes, it locks immediately. As I stated, I am unable to select the option to require a password (although it requires one anyway). Besides, I use my computer mostly at home and only my family has access to it, I am not particularly concerned about security.

Comment: @TrumpetDude i have a new idea it could be related to keychain and having to unlock that

Comment: I have also had issues with the keychain, with my computer repeatedly asking me to enter the keychain password sometimes when I wake it up. However, this only happens when I actually log in, not when I type in the password to wake it up.